# Redirect to my app after user reaches destination using Apple maps or Google maps

Tags: ios

Hey Guys I was wondering if there is a way to redirect the user back to my iOS app after they've reached their destination on Apple maps or Google maps. Thanks!

Comment: Please read the help center's [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible if the app you open, is yours as well, then you could add some code there that does that. However, if you are talking about google maps / Apple maps, then that is not the case.

As far as I know, there is no api for that... iOS 9 brought the "back to..." button exactly for these situations which gives the user an easier way of switching back to the opening app.

Question, why to open another app if maps is all you need? You can always implement a map in your app and save the switching...

Comment: The app that I'm creating is a parking app, so Users click on "Get Directions" from my app it opens Apple maps and guides them to the parking spot then after they've reached their destination I want the user to be redirected to my app. I will eventually incorporate maps directly into my app but was wondering if there was any other possible way to do this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry. If you find my answer helpful please choose it as the correct answer. Big thanks! @MohamadMardini